# How do i compute variable in Wolfram?

Tags: wolframalpha

Hello how do i compute this

```
Q=sqrt(P-X^2)  P=1/T_0*(B^2T_b/3+A^2*T_a+AB*T_b),  X=1/T_0*(A*T_a+B*T_b/2)
```

in WolframAlpha?

A B T_a T_b P X abd Q constant numbers

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't get too much from WolframAlpha when you try to compute that, since they are just variables.

If you mean to simplify the expression, try plugging P and X into Q, then type:

```
simplify sqrt(...)
```